# word 2007 - programmaticaly add a quick access icon for a macro, or add a quick shortcut key for a macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to add a macro to the quick access toolbar through vba code.
I am also wondering how to add a macro key shortcut through vba code.

This is all for windows 2007.

Answer (score 0):

For keyboard shortcut, use:

[Application.OnKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195807%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

To add to the quick access toolbar, first, you need a reference to the ribbon itself.  I had a project where I gave my custom ribbon a custom "onload" function, and then captured the ribbon object in that function.  Then, use that object to make changes.  Sadly, sometimes this object "disappears" in VBA, and there's not much you can do except have a backup of the object reference, and usually one of them is still active.

See this link for an add-in approach:

[Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/Customization/Customising%20the%20Ribbon%20-%20Advanced.htm)

I used this [ribbon editor](http://www.andypope.info/vba/ribboneditor.htm) for my project.

Here's how I captured the ribbon object with a custom onload function:

```
'Callback for customUI.onLoad
Sub RibbonLoaded(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set myRibbon = ribbon
    Set myRibbonBackup = ribbon
End Sub
```

I would recommend using the ribbon editor tool I gave you as much as possible, rather than trying to edit the ribbon with VBA--it can be quite difficult.  I've never used VBA to modify the quick access toolbar.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into the add ins.  

I am still looking to solve this issue via code for the quick access toolbar or the shortcut.

Just an fyi, using word 2007, it does not have the methods onkey.  So I need a diffident way to code a short cut for a macro.

Thanks,
Jeff